# Refreshing env variables by sourcing not working

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, path

I installed torch in my MacBook Pro (running El Capitan). Now for using torch, I've to refresh env variables. Official torch document asks me to run `source ~/.profile`. But the terminal is showing **No such file or directory**. Please help.

Edit: Even `~/.bash_profile` is giving **No such file or directory**.

Comment: Have you ~/.bash_profile . See many questions about what are the startup files for bash

Comment: @Mark even `~/.bash_profile` is giving **No such file or directory**.

Comment: Why a **negative vote** for the question BTW?

Comment: Not me but possibly because of a lack of research there are a lot of questions re .profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your Torch installer complained with the following message:

```
Not updating your shell profile.
You might want to
add the following lines to your shell profile:

. ~/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

You should manually add the suggested line to your profile. If you use `bash` (which is default on OS X) you can do it by:

```
echo . ~/torch/install/bin/torch-activate >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and restart your shell, i.e. close and reopen the Terminal.

This will have the same effect as suggested `source ~/.profile` (so you don't have to run it).

Comment: If you source a file in your current terminal session then there is no need to close and reopen the Terminal application. Also, you should enclose whatever you wish to echo (print) with quotes.

Comment: @fd0 I don't see a reason to quote anything in `echo . ~/torch/install/bin/torch-activate >> ~/.bash_profile` - it will resolve to full path before adding. What's the danger in your opinion?

Comment: No danger, it works fine. It's developing good habits. At some point you will run into the shell's word splitting feature. So, always quote strings that contain spaces. As an example try- `printf '%s\n' foo bar` then add quotes around `foo bar`.

Comment: But you can't proclaim a universal rule "you should". If I wanted expanded path to be added to `.bash_profile` I can't use quotes.